# Objection js update with increments +1

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, objection.js

How i can update value in database using objection ?
My SQL query works perfect.

```
UPDATE "freePlace"
SET number = number-1
WHERE   date >= '2017-10-20'   AND date <= '2017-10-30' AND "idObject" = '1'
```

My objection code:

```
FreePlace.query().patch({number:number+1}).where('date', '>=', startDate)
  .andWhere('date', '<=', endDate)
  .andWhere('idParking', '=', parkingId)
```

Problem is in patch({number:number+1}) 
how i need do this ?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `increment`/`decrement` methods:

```
FreePlace.query()
  .increment('number', 1)
  .where('date', '>=', startDate)
  .andWhere('date', '<=', endDate)
  .andWhere('idParking', '=', parkingId)
```

If you need to update something else in the same query, you can use `raw`

```
FreePlace.query()
  .patch({
    number: raw('number + 1'),
    somethingElse: 42
  })
  .where('date', '>=', startDate)
  .andWhere('date', '<=', endDate)
  .andWhere('idParking', '=', parkingId)
```

`raw` comes from `const { raw } = require('objection')`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need to use ref().  The code as you have it won't know where to get the value of "number+1".

How about this?

```
FreePlace.query().patch({number:ref('number')+1})
  .where('date', '>=', startDate)
  .andWhere('date', '<=', endDate)
  .andWhere('idParking', '=', parkingId)
```

See this example from objection.js docs:

```
Person
  .query()
  .patch({
    age: Person.query().avg('age'),
    firstName: Person.raw("'Jenni' || 'fer'"),
    oldLastName: ref('lastName')
  });
```